# How to create items programmatically in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

In the content tree, the structure is as follows

```
Home
 -England
 -France
 -Germany
```

There is a sublayout (CommentsForm.ascx), which is used in all the 3 pages. When user browses 'France' and submits a comment, the 'Comment' item should get saved under 'France' and so on..

In this scenario, the Parent item (under which the new item has to be created), is dynamic. So, how to get the parent item in such case. Is this correct?

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Sitecore.Data.Database masterDB =   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

 Item parentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;

 string name = "Comment_" + Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoNow;
 TemplateItem template = masterDb.GetTemplate("/sitecore/templates/userdefined/Comment");     

 using (new SecurityDisabler())
 {
   //how to go about here??
   //newItem["Author"] = txtAuthor.text;
   //newItem["CommentText"] = txtComments.Text;
   //parentItem.Add("name", template);
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't i understand the question, you seems to already to use Sitecore.Context.Item which is the right way to get the "dynamic" page item

Comment: If you debug, what item is parentItem? Is it France? Your code looks right.

Comment: I'd really look at doing this a different way. You should not be giving your delivery server access to your master database. Also - depending on how many comments users create - that is going to have serious performance implications on your site. You should not have more than 100 child items.  If you want comments you would be better off looking at a commenting system, or storing the comments in a separate DB outside of Sitecore. Sitecore content items should _only_ be for content editable data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use UserSwitcher safer in production, but you can also use SecurityDisabler using(newSecurityDisabler()){}

Editing and renaming must happen in an Editing.BeginEdit() transaction

```
 Sitecore.Data.Database masterDB =   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

 Item parentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;

 string name = "Comment_" + Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoNow;
 var template = masterDb.GetTemplate("/sitecore/templates/userdefined/Comment");     

using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
try
{
  Item newItem = parentItem.Add("Name", template);
  if (newItem!=null)
  {
    newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
   newItem["Author"] = txtAuthor.text;
   newItem["CommentText"] = txtComments.Text;
   newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
  }
}
catch
    {
      newItem.Editing.CancelEdit();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Create items programmatically based on template in sitecore](https://itsmycode.com/create-items-programmatically-based-template-sitecore/) using the simple code

```
// The SecurityDisabler is required which will overrides the current security model, allowing the code
// to access the item without any security. 
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
  // Get the master database
  Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master");
  // Get the template for which you need to create item
  Items.TemplateItem template = master.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/Sample/Sample Item");
 
  // Get the place in the site tree where the new item must be inserted
  Item parentItem = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
 
  // Add the item to the site tree
  Item newItem = parentItem.Add("NameOfNewItem", template);
 
  // Set the new item in editing mode
  // Fields can only be updated when in editing mode
  // (It's like the begin transaction on a database)
  newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
  try
  {
  // Assign values to the fields of the new item
  newItem.Fields["Title"].Value = "NewValue1";
  newItem.Fields["Text"].Value = "NewValue2";
 
  // End editing will write the new values back to the Sitecore
  // database (It's like commit transaction of a database)
  newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
  // Log the message on any failure to sitecore log
  Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Could not update item " + newItem.Paths.FullPath + ": " + ex.Message, this);
 
  // Cancel the edit (not really needed, as Sitecore automatically aborts
  // the transaction on exceptions, but it wont hurt your code)
  newItem.Editing.CancelEdit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{

    Item newItem = parentItem.Add("Name", TemplateItem.TemplateId);
    newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();

    newItem.Fields[Constants.IDs.Fields.SicParent.Code].Value = row.SicCode.ToString();
    newItem.Fields[Constants.IDs.Fields.SicParent.Description].Value = row.Description;

    // this field is a DropList        
    newItem.Fields[Constants.IDs.Fields.SicParent.Grouping].SetValue(groupItem, true);

    newItem.Editing.EndEdit();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add and item to `parentItem` and then edit the new item like this:

```cs
using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
    Item newItem = parentItem.Add("name", template);
    newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
    newItem["Author"] = txtAuthor.text;
    newItem["CommentText"] = txtComments.Text;
    newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```